# jQuery mobile - panel style removed when loading from any page other than initial one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery mobile site with 2 pages loaded into one html file that use the same panel, which is also in the file, just outside of all the data-rol="page" divs. The problem is when you reload the second page, as in visit before using the first page, the jQuery mobile styling on the ul in the panel is gone.

I've tried adding enhanceWithin() to the code after creating the panel but I must be missing something, it's loading the same panel, how is the style lost if reloaded from another page?

Source

```
<div data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel" data-theme="b"  id="page">

    <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Alpha</h1>    
        <a href="#left-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>                                        
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>News and Features</h1>
        <a href="#page2"><p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <p>Content TBD</p>
    </div>

</div>

<div data-role="page" class="ui-responsive-panel" data-theme="b"  id="page2">

    <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Alpha</h1>    
        <a href="#left-panel" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>                                        
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>News and Features</h1>
        <a href="#page"><p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <p>Content TBD</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

and script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var panel = '<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-position="right" data-display="push"><h1>Panel</h1><ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b"><li><a href="#">test</a></li><li>test2</li></ul></div>';
$(document).one('pagebeforecreate', function () {
  $.mobile.pageContainer.prepend(panel);
  $("#left-panel").panel(); 
});
</script>
```

**Edit:** This is weird to explain, so if you visit the first page, `id=page` the menu loads up with the traditional jQuery mobile styling. If you navigate to the second page(`id=page"`) after starting on that first page, the styling is fine. **IF** you, now on `id="page2"` hit the 'reload' button on your browser the style for the panel is gone, and it remains gone if you navigate back to `id="page"`. So unless the first page is the starting point, the style is never applied, does that make sense?

Comment: can clarify your question and code of how you visit second page first?

Comment: I update the post a bit, hopefully this explains it better, it's a weird problem.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem, however, `$("#left-panel").panel().enhanceWithin();` should solve the problem. check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/WRDgf/1/show/#p2) this goes directly to page2. Panel is styled and accessible from all pages.

Comment: **[This](http://ryanbend.com/test6.html)** is the page I'm having trouble with, when you click the link to page 2 then reload, the style on the panel is gone.

Comment: you're calling `.panel().enhanceWithin()` twice. Also, place your code in head and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I updated **[this](http://ryanbend.com/test6.html)** page with the changes but I still have the same issue, it just reverts to standard html list format.

Comment: remove `$(function() {
$( "[data-role='panel']" ).panel().enhanceWithin();
});
` and add `.enhacenWithin()` to `.panel()` in `pagebeforecreate` event. Try using `.append` instead of `.prepend`.

Comment: That did it! I'm assuming that having enhanceWithin() outside the initial function was why it would only catch on the initial page. Thank you so much @Omar, you're a saint.

Answer (score 0):

On load of the second page use:

```
.trigger('create');
```

Use this to recreate panel on page 2.

More Here:

[Reference](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)

Comment: he is using jQM 1.4, `.trigger("create")` is deprecated.